# When did the modern discourse of equality develop?

Tags: political-history, human-rights

I know that racial segregation was gone by the end of 1968, and that New Zealand allowed Women to vote in 1893, from which most of the world followed. But, the thought of a world where everyone, regardless of religion, race, gender, ethnicity, sexuality, should be treated equally is a relatively new idea.

When did we start aspiring to achieve something like the modern notion of equality?

Comment: Have "we" reached that point yet? Look at the bathroom debate in the US, homophobia in Russia, etc.

Comment: There is no evidence that there was ever a time when everyone was treated equally; there is much evidence to the contrary. It is possible that you meant to ask "When did we first aspire to treat everyone equally?"   (in which case the answer is probably between 1776 and 1793, possibly influenced by earlier Swiss efforts).  But the question as stated is more political than  historical.

Comment: You might want to look into [the history of "human rights" as an idea.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_human_rights)  There's no one point at which everyone woke up and said "Hey guys, let's treat everyone equally!";  there was rather a gradual expansion of the idea over the centuries/millenia.

Comment: Also you need to be specific about what you mean as equal, and all people.  Equal rights at trial in the US is very old, were as equal right to vote based on gender and race are more recent.  There is still massive discrimination based on age (if you are under 18 you can't vote in the US, or sign legal documents) and there seems to be very little push to fix this inequality.  Also most employers discriminate heavily based on applicants ability to do their job, (its hard to get hired as a musician if you lack any musical talent) this also is technically not treating people equally.

Comment: I like that it appears you are willing to modify your question to better fit according to what issues have been raised. However, _"Racial segregation was gone by the end of 1968"_ ... legal segregation in the US maybe... however please look up [Apartheid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apartheid)... I might suggest adding _in the US_ in that sentence before the first comma...

Comment: In addition, equality as an ideal is simply not the same everywhere, even today. Look at the unequal treatment of women in many many countries, and religions. The men are quite content with the status quo and believe their way to be best, so who is this _WE_ you posit?

Comment: To some extent I think a measure of equality is inherent in social animals. *We* are equals as our pack of species, as opposed to other packs or species. Of course, there is a certain measure of inequality inherent as well since social organization usually involves some sort of hierarchy. But working together as a pack requires some understanding or instinct that each member of the pack can do the same/similar things.

Comment: Immediately after God created Adam but before he created eve.